# how to replace a portion of a string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string matrix filled with data like

```
matrix = ['1231231.jpeg','4343.jpeg',...]
```

and I want to remove its file extension and get

```
matrix  = ['1231231', '4343']
```

How can I do it? is there any function or what :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the matrix looks like

```
 matrix = ['1231231.jpeg';
           '4343.jpeg';
            ....];
```

(; instead of ,). If ',' is used, the chars in the matrix are concatinated automatically.

You can use `arrayfun` to perform an operation on each index of a matrix. The following command should work

```
arrayfun(@(x) matrix(x,1:strfind(a(matrix,:),'.jpeg')-1), str2num(matrix(:,1))', 'UniformOutput' , false)
```

Comment: `arrayfun` doesn't buy you much performance over a loop as it uses a loop internally. While this "works" a more readable solution would be to simply write it as a loop without the anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

User fileparts, it returns three variables the `path`, `name`, and `extension` of the file. So this should work for you

```
[~, fName, ext] = fileparts(fileName)
```

Comment: but there is no path for my case

Comment: then ignore that output arg (as @slayton did by using `~`)

Comment: but also I need to do it to each element of the matrix and eliminate the extension for each element . How could I do that any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

there is a function for this in matlab

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileparts.html

```
file = 'H:\user4\matlab\classpath.txt';
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(file)

pathstr =
H:\user4\matlab

name =
classpath

ext =
.txt
```

Comment: there is no path bro for my case

Comment: then the pathstr will be empty or something like it

Answer (score 1):

You could always loop through them and parse them like:

```
r[i] = regexp(char(string), '(?<dec>\d*).(?<ext>\w*)', 'names');
```

use r[i].dec for the number value.

Answer (score 1):

Note: A matrix from (vertical) concatenation of strings with different lengths will not work (except for the special case of equal-length strings). Each char is treated as a single matrix element by `vertcat` when calling`[A;B].`

Alternative, using cell array and `cellfun` (+independent of file extensions):

```
matrix = {'1231231.jpeg','4343.jpeg'};
matrix_name = cellfun(@(x) x(1:find(x == '.', 1, 'last')-1), matrix, 'UniformOutput', false);
```